# Why does folder path created using os path join does not resolve properly?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, os.path

I am creating a folder path as:

```
writeloc = "s3://mybucket/yada/yada/"
write_path = os.path.join(writeloc,"temp_write") + os.sep
```

but when i try to savea  parquet to this location as:

```
write_df.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").save('"{}"'.format(write_path))
```

it gives me the following error:

```
'java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: "s3://mybucket/yada/yada/temp_write/%22'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 738, in save
    self._jwrite.save(path)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 79, in deco
    raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: 'java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: "s3://mybucket/yada/yada/temp_write/%22'
```

Why is it changing my double quote(") in the end of the path resolution to %22' ?

Comment: What is `write_path`? Does it include the `s3://` part?

Comment: Added more info to the question.  Yes it does include the s3:// part

Comment: I think the short answer is to not add those extra quotes in the string. The error is complaining about index 0. URLs start with a scheme, and you've given a scheme of `"s3:` which is not valid. Later parts of the URL may need to encode the other quote as `%22`. The fix is to not do the extra quoting. `'"{}"'.format(write_path)` should likely just be `write_path`.

Comment: ```write_path = os.path.join(writeloc,"temp_write","") 
print('Writing to {}'.format(write_path)) ``` gives me  Writing to s3://s3://mybucket/yada/yada/temp_write/. How do I make sure it gives me "Writing to s3://mybucket/yada/yada/temp_write/"

Comment: Not sure how that double `s3://s3://` got there. You only want one. If you need the forward slash on the end of the url, then os.sep works ... on linux/mac but not windows (whose separator is a backslash). Since this is a url, not a file system path that needs platform dependent rules a-la `os.path`, you can just use the forward slash.  `write_path = f"{writeloc}/temp_write/"`.

Comment: ```write_path = f"{writeloc}/temp_write/"
print('"{}"'.format(write_path))
write_df.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").save('"{}"'.format(write_path))```

Same traceback %22 stuff

Comment: This print statement shows it to be fine. It gunks out at the parquet save method..

Comment: You keep adding those extra quotes. Try not doing that. Is there some reason why those are required?